# Waiting until a callback will return a value in FOR loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have to detect if some technologies is valid for my web browser, and i don't know how to wait until a function which contains a callback returns some value in FOR loop.

```
interface IVerify {
    verify: () => boolean;
}

class A {
    verifiers: Array<IVerify>

    constructor() {
        this.verifiers = new Array<IVerify>();
    }

    public regist(x: IVerify) {
        this.verifiers.push(x);
    }

    public verifyVerifiers() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.verifiers.length; ++i) {
            alert(this.verifiers[i].verify());
        }
    }
}

class B implements IVerify {
    verify(): boolean {
        return true;
    }
}

class C implements IVerify {
    verify(): boolean {
        var valid: boolean;
        var fs: any = (<any>window).RequestFileSystem || (<any>window).webkitRequestFileSystem;
        fs((<any>window).TEMPORARY, 1, (fs) => {
            valid = true;
        }, (err) => {
            valid = false;
        });           
        return valid;
    }
}

var a: A = new A();
var b: B = new B();
var c: C = new C();
a.regist(b);
a.regist(c);
a.verifyVerifiers();
```

How can I wait until c.verify() returns true/false (now it returns undefined).

Comment: try `public regist(x: IVerify, callback) {
        this.verifiers.push(x);
if(callback)
   callback();
    }` and pass function as a callback

Comment: @johndorian: OT: use rather `console.log()` instead of `alert()`, it gives you better information in many cases.

Comment: @MartinVseticka still undefined...  Rajesh, why should i do it in regist function? I want to verify it in verifyVerifiers function.

Comment: Well, you can't make the code synchronous. It's a pity but it's how it is in JavaScript. You can add a promise and it will help you to manage your result. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ However, it requires you to read at least that article (10 - 15 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I believe this may help you a bit - it's in pure JavaScript:

```
var promises = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    promises.push(
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

      window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, function onInitFs() {
        resolve("Stuff worked!");
      }, function errorHandler() {  
        reject(Error("It broke"));
      });
    })
  );
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lc1smhbq/1/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all